# How do I combine different DR?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage-reduction

I'm creating a bad guy who is *half-fiend*, which gives him **DR** 5/magic.

He's going to cast *righteous might* which then gives him **DR** 5/good.

What is the resulting stat block? Do they need both *magic* and *good* to bypass the DR? Either *magic* or *good*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very strictly speaking, the creature has the better at any given instant of *DR 5/magic* and *DR 5/good*. Multiple sources of [Damage Reduction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Damage-Reduction) don't stack with each other (with a handful of very specific exceptions, which call themselves out); rather, the creature is considered to have whichever source's DR is best for that particular situation (on a per-attack or per-effect basis).

In practice, this particular combination is equivalent to having *DR 5/magic and good*, but that's technically a quirk of how they interact.

If the creature is attacked with a magic weapon, the *DR 5/good* would be more advantageous, so that's what is in effect for that attack. Similarly, if they were attacked with a good-aligned weapon that wasn't magic somehow (probably the natural or non-magical weapons of a [good](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Good-Subtype) creature), the *DR 5/magic* would be better, and thus would be in effect. Of course, a +1 [Holy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy/) weapon would ignore both of the DR sources.

Thus, while the creature technically has *DR 5/magic* and *DR 5/good*, it effectively has *DR 5/magic and good*.

Where this hair-splitting becomes more important is if they have, say, DR *5/good* from one source and *DR 10/magic* from another source.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [damage reduction rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Damage-Reduction):

> If a creature has damage reduction from more than one source, the two forms of damage reduction do not stack. Instead, the creature gets the benefit of the best damage reduction in a given situation.

Meaning that if you have damage reduction against magic and good, the attack must be of **both types** to ignore your damage reduction completely, which reads as **DR 5/magic and good**.